# Storybook - Tailwind Error var api = require("!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, postcss

I have an issue running the Tailwind in Storybook.

my **postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
```

and I add the tailwind css in index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

to have it in the preview.js I add import

```
import '../src/index.css';
```

and the error is:

```
 var api = require("!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-oneOf-4-1!../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss!./index.css");
  3 |
```

How I can add the tailwind CSS to be global in storybook?
Thx!!!